# Can't change pelican theme

Tags: python, pelican

I'm trying to change default pelican theme to [this one](https://github.com/jody-frankowski/blue-penguin/tree/fb1508845764d1e7bde71863f2540fa1829b470a).
However changes do not appear when I use

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

I installed the theme using `pelican-themes --install` and I can say that installation went all right because when I run `pelican-themes -l` the theme is listed:

```
notmyidea
simple
blue-penguin
```

I added this to my pelicanconf.py:

```
THEME = "blue-penguin"
```

And it's not the browser cache because I also added this:

```
LOAD_CONTENT_CACHE = False
```

I tried running

```
 pelican content -s ../pelicanconf.py
```

but had no result.

Even using trying the default themes `notmyidea` and `simple` doesn't work.

Any idea of what is going on?

**EDIT:** adding my pelicanconf.py, as requested:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*- #
from __future__ import unicode_literals

AUTHOR = u'My Name'
SITENAME = u'Programa\xe7\xe3o, estat\xedstica e mais'
SITEURL = ''
GITHUB_URL = 'http://github.com/EuPaulo'
LOCALE = 'pt_BR.utf8'
THEME = u"blue-penguin"
LOAD_CONTENT_CACHE = False

RELATIVE_URLS = True

PATH = 'content'

TIMEZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'

DEFAULT_LANG = u'pt'

# Feed generation is usually not desired when developing
FEED_ALL_ATOM = None
CATEGORY_FEED_ATOM = None
TRANSLATION_FEED_ATOM = None
AUTHOR_FEED_ATOM = None
AUTHOR_FEED_RSS = None

# Blogroll
# LINKS = (('Pelican', 'http://getpelican.com/'),
 #        ('Python.org', 'http://python.org/'),
  #       ('Jinja2', 'http://jinja.pocoo.org/'),
   #      ('You can modify those links in your config file', '#'),)

# Social widget
SOCIAL = (('twitter', 'https://twitter.com/paulomiramor'),
          ('linkedin', 'http://www.linkedin.com/in/XXXXXXX'),
          ('github', 'https://github.com/EuPaulo'),)

DEFAULT_PAGINATION = 5
```

Comment: Pelican is a static site generator. What do you need SimpleHTTPServer for?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Just following the guidelines in the documentation: http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.0/publish.html#site-generation

Comment: It would help if you show your config file but a wild guess: try setting `RELATIVE_URLS = True`.

Comment: Also a side note: `pelican` cache (`LOAD_CONTENT_CACHE` setting) isn't at all related to browser cache. `pelican` cache is about speeding up process times for unmodified content.

Comment: @Avaris Thanks for the information about `LOAD_CONTENT_CACHE`. I tried setting `RELATIVE_URLS = True` but it didn't work. I pasted my pelicanconf.py in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running the SimpleHTTPServer into the output directory? If not the static url resolution will fail because the root directory for the website will not be the good one.

If this is good, can you paste your pelicanconf.py somewhere please so that we can check if there is nothing wrong.

Comment: Yes, I'm running the `SimpleHTTPServer` into the output directory. I pasted the pelicanconf.py in the question.

Comment: For some reason I created an output inside my content folder, and I was running `SimpleHTTPServer` inside this folder. Your answer helpful in figuring this out, so I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks.